# CALayer not showing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation

In trying to make a draggable sort of CALayer ( [Question on Stack Overflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127688/draggable-calayer/) ) I tried creating a window through code and adding a CALayer to it, but I don't get why it's not showing.

```
NSRect rect = NSZeroRect;
    rect.size = NSMakeSize( SSRandomFloatBetween( 300.0, 200.0 ), SSRandomFloatBetween( 300.0, 200.0 ));

    NSWindow *newWin = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:rect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSWindowBackingLocationDefault defer:YES];
    [newWin setBackgroundColor: [NSColor clearColor]];
    [newWin setOpaque:NO];
    [newWin setIgnoresMouseEvents:NO];
    [newWin setMovableByWindowBackground:YES];
    [newWin makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];

    [[newWin contentView] setWantsLayer:YES];

    NSRect contentFrame = [[newWin contentView] frame];
    CALayer *newWinLayer = [CALayer layer];
    newWinLayer.frame = NSRectToCGRect(contentFrame);

    layer.backgroundColor=CGColorCreateGenericGray(0.0f, 0.5f);
    layer.borderColor=CGColorCreateGenericGray(0.756f, 0.5f);
    layer.borderWidth=5.0;

        // Calculate random origin point
    rect.origin = SSRandomPointForSizeWithinRect( rect.size, [window frame] );

        // Set the layer frame to our random rectangle.
    layer.frame = NSRectToCGRect(rect);
    layer.cornerRadius = 25.0f;
  [newWinLayer addSublayer:layer];
```

"Window" is linked to a big window, with a semi-transparent (black filled) window that is resized to fill the screen.

I've made the window draggable, but why isn't the CALayer in the window showing?

Answer (score 2):

```
NSRect rect = NSZeroRect;

rect.size = NSMakeSize( SSRandomFloatBetween( 300.0, 200.0 ),
      SSRandomFloatBetween( 300.0, 200.0 ));

NSWindow *newWin = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:rect
            styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
           backing:NSWindowBackingLocationDefault defer:YES];

[newWin setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
[newWin setOpaque:NO];
[newWin setIgnoresMouseEvents:NO];
[newWin setMovableByWindowBackground:YES];
[newWin makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];

// you don't want to do this yet
// [[newWin contentView] setWantsLayer:YES];

NSRect contentFrame = [[newWin contentView] frame];
CALayer *newWinLayer = [CALayer layer];
newWinLayer.frame = NSRectToCGRect(contentFrame);
```

Line break, also a memory-managment issue:

```
// NOTE: remember that the following 2 *Create* methods return
//  results that need to be released, unless you're using Garbage-Collection
// Also, I'm guessing that `layer` is created somewhere?
CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
CGColorRef backgroundCol = CGColorCreateGenericGray(0.0f, 0.5f);
CGColorRef borderCol = CGColorCreateGenericGray(0.756f, 0.5f);

layer.backgroundColor=backgroundCol;
layer.borderColor=borderCol;
CGColorRelease(backgroundCol); CGColorRelease(borderCol);
layer.borderWidth=5.0;

    // Calculate random origin point
rect.origin = SSRandomPointForSizeWithinRect( rect.size, [window frame] );

    // Set the layer frame to our random rectangle.
layer.frame = NSRectToCGRect(rect);
layer.cornerRadius = 25.0f;

[newWinLayer addSublayer:layer];

NSView *view = [newWin contentView];

// the order of the following 2 methods is critical:

[view setLayer:newWinLayer];
[view setWantsLayer:YES];
```

See NSView's documentation for [`setWantsLayer:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/setWantsLayer%3a)

> **Discussion** 
>   The order that
>   `setWantsLayer:` and `setLayer:` are
>   called is important, it makes the
>   distinction between a layer-backed
>   view, and a layer-hosting view.
>
> A layer-backed view is a view that is
>   backed by a Core Animation layer. Any
>   drawing done by the view is the cached
>   in the backing layer. You configured a
>   layer-backed view by simply invoking
>   `setWantsLayer:` with a value of `YES`.
>   The view class will automatically
>   create the a backing layer for you,
>   and you use the view class’s drawing
>   mechanisms. **When using layer-backed
>   views you should never interact
>   directly with the layer**.
>
> A layer-hosting view is a view that
>   contains a Core Animation layer that
>   you intend to manipulate directly. You
>   create a layer-hosting view by
>   instantiating an instance of a Core
>   Animation layer class and setting that
>   layer using the view’s `setLayer:`
>   method. After doing so, you then
>   invoke `setWantsLayer:` with a value of
>   YES. **When using a layer-hosting view
>   you should not rely on the view for
>   drawing, nor should you add subviews
>   to the layer-hosting view**.

I believe the way you were doing it would be trying to create a layer-backed view, where you shouldn't be trying to interact with the view's underlying layer like you were. What you want is the layer-hosting variety.